# Can't enable user theme extension

Tags: gnome, themes

I've searched in Google and looked in another questions, but still I can't solve this problem! I want to install GNOME-shell theme. So I'm trying to enable user-theme-extension in GNOME tweak tool. But I can't enable it. It has a yellow triangle near it says

> "extensions does not support shell version"

What should I do? How can I install GNOME shell themes?

Answer (score 3):

you are using gnome-tweak tool....,following this step

```
1. Shell Extensions -> user theme Extension --> enable(on)
2. alt + f2 -> "r" -> enter
```

Backing to gnome-tweak, you go to the Theme. You will see a workable function of shell-theme.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use firefox or chrome to install the add-on from the website, you should use the default gnome browser which goes by the names web and epiphany.

Comment: how to open gnome browser?

Answer (score 0):

This means the gnome-shell version you are using is not matching with the version the extension was made for.

Are you on Ubuntu 12.04? the [official gnome3 ppa](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=precise) doesn't provide the `gnome-shell-extensions` package for Precise(12.04). But the [Gnome-shell testing ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ricotz/+archive/testing/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=precise) does. So you can try adding it to your list of repositories. But use caution because they are unstable builds.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the webupd8 gnome3 ppa. This ppa has some of the best gnome-shell extensions, including the user-theme extension. you can add this ppa by typing the following in the terminal:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gnome3`

followed by:

`sudo apt-get update`

next try installing user-theme extension with:

`sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme`

This works for me on my version of gnome-shell, if it doesn't work please post your version of gnome-shell here.

source: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/official-gnome-shell-extensions.html

Comment: didn't work for me.. still - I can't enable the User themes extension in the "SHELL EXTENSIONS" section.. how do I know my shell version?

Comment: type in terminal `gnome-shell --version`

Comment: try `git clone git://git.gnome.org/gnome-shell-extensions` then go in that directory `cd gnome-shell-extensions` then do `./autogen.sh –prefix=$HOME/.local – enable-extensions=”user-theme"`. Log out and in, and check if it works. this version should work with gnome-shell version 3.5.2 (there's not yet a version 3.5.3 available)

Answer (score 0):

Search a ppa for your version of Ubuntu that contains the gnome-shell-extensions package:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=gnome-shell-extensions 
For Precise, https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/gnome works perfectly.
Install this package, and the user-themes extensions from [extensions.gnome.org](https://extensions.gnome.org) will function correctly.